# Question Migrate to SuperUser

Tags: feature-request, migration

I have become slightly annoyed with all the on hold tech support questions.

If a question is migrated does it leave HR?

If it does it seems like they sit around for a long time on HR.

Is there a way for us to speedup this process to kick them over to SU?

Comment: [Main meta answer to how migrations work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work). As for migrating away, I think you'd be disappointed to learn that of the questions we've migrated to Super User, only one has received an answer. The others have been almost entirely ignored

Comment: @Andy I actually stopped coming to this site because there is too much garbage all over the place.  Every other question is on hold.  I have actually come to the site to see every question on the front page [on hold]

Comment: I agree with you Jeff. I've been trying to come up with a proposal or seven that would help with the number of questions we have on hold. If you have suggestions, I encourage you to post them as separate meta topics so they can be discussed. I understand the frustration though. I don't like seeing everything on hold either.

Comment: @Andy I have some ideas and I will post them tomorrow after I think everything through.  Don't want to get beat up for not researching previous meta.

Answer (score 1):

Rule #1 of migrations: "Don't migrate crap".

SuperUser has enough of a problem with people asking low-quality questions that need to be closed or are duplicates of existing questions.  Most of the tech-support questions on this site fall into one or the other of those groups, so there's no point in migrating them rather than closing them ourselves.

In the rare event that a question does get migrated, the migration will happen as soon as the question is placed on hold.  A copy of the question will stick around on HR for 30 days to act as a pointer to the new location, before being automatically deleted.

Comment: I already read about the low quality questions etc.  My question was 2 parts.  1 about operation of the migration and what happens to the question and if it is removed from HR