# Why deleting questions instead of using site mechanics?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, deleted-questions

A couple of hours ago I've [asked a question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/12113/edit) and now it is closed and **deleted** with resolution

> "**Technical support request** — Questions asking about **troubleshooting hardware** or **technical support for hardware** are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com)." – ArtOfCode

So:

1. Why closed questions are immediately deleted if site engine will do it after one month?
2. If that question suites for Super User, why deletion is used instead of migration?

Comment: [Related](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/622/lets-clean-up-some-broken-windows-a-proposal-for-dealing-with-tech-support-qu)

Answer (score 3):

This site works differently to other sites on the Stack Exchange network. Because of the strict topicality and quality requirements for questions, both fast-closure (from mods and regular users - we have one-vote closure) and fast-deletion are used to manage the significant influx of off-topic questions.

If a question is on-topic but doesn't meet the standards we have for questions here, I will close the question, but leave it undeleted so that it can be edited into shape and reopened. For questions which are unsalvageably off-topic, I close and immediately delete the question, because there's no point in keeping it around.

As an experienced high-rep user *and moderator* on other Stack Exchange sites, I was extremely surprised that you didn't read the help center first - that would have told you that your question was off-topic in the first few lines.

Comment: You haven't answered about migration.

Comment: @Qwertiy Because it's not important. "You may get help on SU" is not the same as "this question is on-topic on SU". I don't know SU's scope, nor is it on me to go and find out for you; look at their help center.